# GPU programming affects image transfer from a camera

Tags: android, c++, opencv, opencl, hardware

I'm currently working on image tracking: thanks to a camera I'm tracking finger touches that interact with an Android system. Image processing is done on a GPU with OpenCL: I convert the camera output into black and white frames in order to get the spots in white. The processing time is 65ms with this method. Since my objective is to make the program smoother, I've performed the same operations on a CPU with an OpenCV method. That gives a processing time of 115ms. The problem is that the program feels more reactive, faster with the OpenCV method.

I found out why it feels halting: it's because the time for grabbing a frame passes from 5ms to 15ms. It might be because I create a buffer which decreases the bandwidth. The programming on GPU is faster than on CPU but it affects the image/sec.

Do you know if there is a way to use GPU programming without affecting the grab of the images from the cameras? 
(I work on an android xu4)

Comment: pipeline them so one latency is hidden

Comment: can you try to find out whether it is some kind of bandwidth problem or a processing problem? For example try to upload some data to your GPU and perform a gpu task that will compute for a long time asynchronously. Then only use CPU camera capturing and processing. If your capturing is still slow then, I would think the camera capturing uses the GPU (maybe for some image improvement?) and this could explain your problem.

Comment: Thank you Micka, I will try this !

Comment: OK! I ran a program which do some image processing on GPU at the same time of my main program and the time for grabbing an image from the camera is still the same!

Comment: same 5ms or same 15ms? Btw, if you have 65ms GPU + 15ms CPU capturing it should still be more responsive than 115ms all on CPU...

Comment: Same 5ms. CPU = 115ms / GPU = 65ms (time for a loop). In fact it's faster but it's halting because the IPS are lower. This test means that I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: or does OpenCL consume both, maximum CPU and GPU ressources, simultaneously? Did you use similar gpu methods in your application an in the test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126908/discussion-between-a-kriss-and-micka).